# How is irange() any different from range() or xrange()?

Tags: python, range, generator, xrange

I was going through Python Generators Wiki when I came across this [RangeGenerator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/RangeGenerator) page which talks about `irange()`  -

> This will let us iterator over large spans of numbers without
>   resorting to xrange, which is a lazy list as opposed to a generator.

I can't seem to understand the test suite and the implementation described on that page. I know that `range()` creates a list in the memory (from Python 2.7 point of view) and `xrange()` is a generator. How is `irange()` any different?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`irange()` returns a generator type, which *can only be iterated over*. Nothing else. Once you iterated over it, the generator is exhausted and can not be iterated over again.

The Python 2 [`xrange()` type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) and Python 3 [`range()` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) are *sequence types*, they support various operations that other sequences support as well, such as reporting on their length, test for containment, and indexing:

```
>>> xr = xrange(10, 20, 3)
>>> len(xr)
4
>>> 10 in xr
True
>>> xr[0]
10
>>> xr[1]
13
```

You can iterate over these objects more than once:

```
>>> for i in xr:
...     print i,
... 
10 13 16 19
>>> for i in xr:
...     print i,
... 
10 13 16 19
```

You can even use the [`reversed()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) to iterate over them *in reverse*, efficiently:

```
>>> for i in reversed(xr):
...     print i,
... 
19 16 13 10
```

The Python 3 `range()` type is an improved version of `xrange()`, in that it supports more sequence operations, is more efficient still, and can handle values beyond `sys.maxint` (what would be a `long` integer in Python 2).

It supports slicing, for example, which results in a *new* `range()` object for the sliced values:

```
>>> r = range(10, 20, 3)
>>> r[:2]
range(10, 16, 3)
```

You can use negative indices just like you can with other Python sequences, to get elements counting from the end:

```
>>> r[-2]
16
>>> r[-2:]
range(16, 22, 3)
```

and the type supports testing for equality; two `range()` instances are equal if they'd yield the same values:

```
>>> range(10, 20, 3) == range(10, 21, 3)
True
```

In Python 2, the only advantage the generator `irange()` might have is that it doesn't suffer from the limitation to non-long integers that `xrange()` is subjected to:

```
>>> import sys
>>> xrange(sys.maxint)
xrange(9223372036854775807)
>>> xrange(sys.maxint + 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Answer (score -2):

irange provides an generator which does not loads entire result into memory. Say you have `range(1, 1000000)` in case a list of 1000000 numbers would be loaded into memory, whereas in case of `xrange(1, 1000000)`, just one number would be in memory at a time.

Comment: You have a typo in your answer, you used `range()` twice. Python 2  also has `xrange()` which also doesn't produce a full list of integers up front. You don't actually answer the question, as to why the `irange()` implementation is different from Python 2's `xrange()` object.