# Why does the 'filling' of my test sqlite db take up so much RAM and doesn't save anything?

Tags: python, sqlite, insert, ram

I have the following script to fill a test database for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random, sys, sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS EXAMPLE")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE(FIRST TEXT, SECOND TEXT)")

for i in range(0, 99999999):
    one = format(i, '08d')
    two = "%0.8d" % random.randint(0,99999999)
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO EXAMPLE VALUES(\'"+one+"\',\'"+two+"\')")

    con.commit()

    # to have some feedback of the progress
    if i % 100000 == 0:
        print (str(i))

con.close()
print ("done")
# wait in the script..
sys.stdin.readline()
```

Now the script takes up all the RAM it can (runs currently in a VM with 3GB - takes up ~2.8GB) within about 2 minutes *(edit: within a few seconds)* and never reached the `if i % 100000 == 0:`.
If I terminate it and check the `test.db` file it's 3KB big and contains the table only, no entries.

Do I need to close and re-open the connection every now and then?

Comment: `for i in range(0, 99999999)` allocates the whole list up front. Try replacing `range` with `irange` as a start. It's implemented as a generator instead and will build a stream instead of a list (conceptually). A list of 100mio entries is a large list :)

Comment: thanks for the info, I've never used `irange`.. how do I use it? Couldn't find it in the python doc..

Comment: Python 2 or 3? If 3, then `range` is fine and doesn't allocate the entire list. If not, use xrange, not irange.

Comment: Also, move `con.commit` to after the loop. Insertions are fast, but commits are really slow, so you want to batch as much work as you can in one commit.

Comment: I could use either - what would you suggest Python 3 with `range` or Python 2 with `xrange`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my comment suggested, you should consider using `irange` instead of `range` when returning lists with many elements in them, especially if you are only going to use the list once.

The difference lies in the implementation. `range` creates the whole list up front, and returns elements from the list.
`irange` just creates and returns the next element from the list each time, and so it doesn't do as much work up front.

The function calls are interchangeable to my knowledge, so just replace `range` in your code with `irange` and you should see less RAM consumption.

Check this question out also: [How is irange() any different from range() or xrange()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22971078/how-is-irange-any-different-from-range-or-xrange)

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I was answering a bit fast. Use `xrange` and not `irange` as I previously wrote.
For when to use one over the other: [Should you always favor xrange() over range()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135041/should-you-always-favor-xrange-over-range)

The reason it doesn't matter if you use range or xrange in Python 3 is, AFAIK because range is implemented as xrange.

Comment: I tried to do so - `for i in irange(0, 99999999):` instead of `for i in range(0, 99999999):`, but i get `NameError: name 'irange' is not defined`

Comment: @DaedalusMythos does a change from `range` to `xrange` make any difference on the RAM consumption :) ?

Comment: yes. absolutely! the RAM consumption is now very low and works as intended!

Comment: @DaedalusMythos That's great! :) I often try to implement list-returning functions that I iterate over, as generators. Whenever something is used like a stream, I prefer a generator. Thanks for accepting my answer :)